# How to create an outgoing connection load balancer with Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to create an instance of an Google Compute Engine instance which can make use of multiple ip addresses to randomize the outgoing connection ip address.

1. Is it possible to assign multiple external ip addresses to one NIC in Google Compute Engine?
2. How do I setup rules so that outgoing connections use different ip addresses at random?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/how-to/networking/using-multiple-ip-addresses

Comment: Thanks John but I read this article previously and this refers to internal ip addresses and not external. I need the connections coming out of the VM to have random external ip addresses. Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Comment: anyone has any advice?

Comment: It is not possible to assign multiple IP in one NIC in GCE as written on the restriction part of [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) documentation. And you can use [Protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding) on setting up rules for your use case.